# in voodoo.js, what event trigger Model's "update" function?

Tags: javascript

In voodoo, the class Model has a method called update. Does that be called automatically every second? or is there any event that will trigger this function?

Answer (score 0):

If the page has focus, and you're using the default options, update() should be getting called all the time. I would check that you don't have the focus on another window (debugger maybe?), and that calling voodoo.engine.frame(), which forces an update, calls update on your model.